# onClickListener not found after rotation in android

Tags: android

This is a stripped down version of what I want to do.  I have some stuff occurring inside the clickListener and want it to continue after orientation change.  I save the variable and in the "if(saveInstanceState != null) section I retrieve the variable "count" and try to start the tasks inside the onClick method.  The variable is saved properly (although not printed because the setText method in inside onClick.  Also, the Log returns "false", meaning that the performClick method executed but did not find the clickListener.

I think this is a scope of variable issue, but am otherwise stumped.  Thanks for any help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button countButton;
    int count = 0;
    TextView countWidget;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        countButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        countWidget = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            count = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
            boolean found = countButton.performClick();
            Log.d("Message ", "found listener = " + found);

        }
        countButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count ++;
                countWidget.setText("count = " + count);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("count", count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling `performClick()` before the call to `setOnClickListener`, thus when `onCreate` is called with your `Bundle`, it cannot find the callback.

The previous call is fine because when the user taps on the button, it's already way past `onCreate` where the callback is defined.

One solution is to move the `Bundle` check after `setOnClickListener`

```
    countButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count ++;
            countWidget.setText("count = " + count);
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
        boolean found = countButton.performClick();
        Log.d("Message ", "found listener = " + found);

    }
```

`performClick` works (without crashing, if that's what you were expecting when the log returns false) because Android will check if there's any click listener defined, if not then just `return false`.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java

```
    if (li != null && li.mOnClickListener != null) {
        playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        li.mOnClickListener.onClick(this);
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the onClick function from the layout file of your activity like this:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/countButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Count"
            android:onClick="onCountClick"/>
```

Now, after adding this to your layout file, define the function `onCountClick` in your activity's java file like this:

```
public void onCountClick(View v)
{
    //Do your tasks here
}
```

If you do this, you won't be needing the `onClickListener` any more.

Hope it helps.